# Why can't I use get with Tkinter askstring?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to fetch a value from a user using simple dialog and insert it into Text Area but I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get
```

My code:

```
def feedialog():
    amt_input = tkSimpleDialog.askstring("Amout","Enter Amount")

txtarea1.insert(END,f"\n Fee :{amt_input.get()}"
```

Comment: So, did you mean: `f"\n Fee :{amt_input}"`?

Comment: Strings don't have a `get` method. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks I got it i was learning to use text area to generate bills

Answer (score 1):

```
amt_input.get()
```

you are calling the `get` method on a `str` object: amt_input is already a string. You should just use:

```
txtarea1.insert(END,f"\n Fee :{amt_input}"
```

Comment: Thankyou very much

Comment: @Rahul98135 if your problem is solved, please mark this answer as solving your problem. This makes it clear for everyone.